# How to implement Publish-subscribe pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have two classes, Database and Logger. Database is responsible for handling SQL queries, and Logger logs messages to an external file. Whenever the database executes an SQL query, I want Logger to log it. Right now my implementation looks something like this:

```
    class Database {
        public function query($sql) {
            Logger::log($sql); 

            // ...
        }
    }

    class Logger {
        public static function log($msg) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

But I feel that this is bad practice because Database shouldn't know about Logger. So instead I was thinking of creating a publisher-subscriber model (or something similar) where Database keeps a list of subscribers and has a method to subscribe to events, then it alerts subscribers when an event is fired (eg: when query is executed). I'm thinking something like this:

```
    class Database {
        $subscribers = array(); 

        public function subscribe($something) {
            $subscribers.push($something);
        }

        private function alert_subscribers($msg, $event_type) {
            foreach ($s as $subscribers) { 
                // Alert all subscribers, somehow
            }
        }

        public function query($sql) {
            alert_subscribers($sql, SQL_QUERY_EXECUTED);

            // ...
        }
    }

    class Logger {
        public static function log($msg) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I want it to have multiple event types, so basically different groups are alerted when different events happen. I also don't know how the Logger should subscribe to Database under this design.

How should I go about implementing this? I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having the loggers everywhere. If you clutter all your classes with some kind of event notification it would look worst :)

**But**, Logger should not be called with a static method. You can create a pool of Loggers and your call will look like:

```
$log=Logger::get("Database");
$log->info("foo");
```

The big advantage is that you can put a configuration file in your project and define the log level of every logger independently.

---

According your questions you have really big plans. You want to write a template engine, a logging framework, an ORM and I guess somewhere in between your real application. Trust me when I tell you, you will fail. (I and most likely everybody else here tried it already :) ). **For all your components there are mature frameworks out there. Find the one you like!!**

Comment: For what it's worth. I think you need to atleast try it once. If you do this, you will learn a lot on how things are build up.

Comment: +1 But you should do it in your spare time not in a project you have to life with the next X years ;)

Comment: That's true! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Event

```
class Event {

    private $_subscribers = array();

    public function Invoke() {
        foreach ($this->_subscribers as $subscriber) {
            call_user_func($subscriber);
            //call_user_func_array($subscriber, array("some argument"));
        }
    }

    public function Subscribe($subscriber) {
        if (!is_callable($subscriber)) {
            throw new \ArgumentException("Subscriber have to be callable");
        }

        $this->_subscribers[] = $subscriber;
    }

    public function UnSubscribe($unsubscriber) {
        foreach ($this->_subscribers as $key => $subscriber) {
            if ($subscriber == $unsubscriber) {
                unset($this->_subscribers[$key]);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public final function __invoke() {
        $this->Invoke();
    }

}
```

I would create at least a simple Event class to keep clean the code. The example above is a very simple one but if you have 5 more minutes for this you can create a DatabaseEvent class which have a Subscribe method what is expecting an IDatabaseEventHandler "interface instance" as parameter (public function Subscribe(IDatabaseEventHandler $handler)) which has a few or a lot of methods: LogConnectionError($arg), LogQueryError(QueryErrorArgument $arg) and so on. Whith this approach you will need an adapter class as a default interface implementation of the IDatabaseEventHandler for easier usage (for example when you are writing your unit tests). Of course the DatabaseEvent class have to have a lot of named log methods to call the subscribed handlers when it's neccessary.